# in c, using if statements with struct items

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to write a recursive function in c that prints a linked list.  Here is my linked list struct:

```
typedef struct list_node{
        char in_data;
        struct list_node *next_item;
        } list_node;
```

Here is my print list function:

```
void print_list(list_node *head_of_list){
        list_node *new_ptr = head_of_list.next_item;
        if(new_ptr == '\0'){
                printf(" %c",  head_of_list->in_data);
        }
        else{
                printf(" %c", head_of_list->in_data);
                print_list(head_of_list->next_item);
        }
        return;
}
```

Here is the error I keep getting:

```
 error: request for member ‘next_item’ in something not a structure or union
```

And the error says it's on the line with the if(new_ptr... statement.  Can anyone help me eliminate this error? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list_node *new_ptr = head_of_list.next_item;`
must be
`list_node *new_ptr = head_of_list->next_item;`

Answer (score 0):

`head_of_list` is not a `list_node`, it's a `list_node*`, that is a pointer to a `list_node`. To access its member, you should write :

```
   head_of_list->next_item;
```